# using visual studio database file as ms sql server for wamp(php with ms sql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, visual-studio

previously i am using php with mysql to work with but due to client requirements i changed from mysql to .net ,c#,Linq and database file  and they said to use visual studio and i downloaded 2012 edition and i am searching for using the previously done php script to work with visual studio database file. so, please tell me the way to access the database.
and i am very new to visual studio and i am searching for database login details..

Comment: have you looked at http://www.connectionstrings.com? Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754501/configure-wamp-to-connect-ms-sql-server-2008

Comment: Yes Mr.@PinnyM i had a deep look at it but i didn't find any connection strings to database file in visual studio. and on creating a database file how can i know the username,password and host in which the database is running.